# programmatically add new fragment causes flicker

Tags: android, fragment, flicker

I have an app. For examples sake, I have an AccountActivity. This activity shows a listview. When an item is clicked (i.e. payment types), I replace the main content with PaymentFragment. When an option is selected within PaymentFragment (i.e. add new credit card), I replace the main content with AddCCFragment. All this is happening within the AccountActivity. I'm just replacing fragments.

The issue is, if I programatically add a fragment within AddCCFragment, the screen will flicker for a brief moment.

Here's an example of an execution with no flicker:

1. AccountActivity has FrameLayout which contains ListView
2. AccountActivity has FrameLayout which contains PaymentFragment
3. AccountActivity has FrameLayout which contains AddCCFragment

Here's an example of an execution with flicker:

1. AccountActivity has FrameLayout which contains ListView
2. AccountActivity has FrameLayout which contains PaymentFragment
3. AccountActivity has FrameLayout which contains AddCCFragment which programmatically adds FragmentABC

A flicker happens on step 3.

Thanks.